# On the imperative mood

Tags: imperative-sentences

I've already learnt that if we want to make a sentence sound like imperative, there is no subject needed as in

> 1.Go see if she is okay!
>
> 2.Tell me if she is okay!

But is it possible to include "you" or "he" to make the sentences sound like imperative as in

> 3.You/he go see if she is okay!
>
> 4.You/he tell me if she is okay!

If my examples are not good for answering my question, you can make other sentences appropriate for this question.

Comment: Your examples 3 and 4 don't work in the imperative, unless you make a pause: "**You!** Go see if she is okay."

Comment: @WeatherVane I've just gotten an answer from a native speaker that this sentence "You go to Sam's room and see if Sam's sleeping" sounds like a command. Do you agree with this opinion?

Comment: Which question / answer is that? It certainly won't be your "3. He go see if she is okay!"

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry for having you confused. I got the answer from a native speaker on a language-exchange app, not here.

Comment: You didn't ask about "You go to Sam's room and see if Sam's sleeping" in this question.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I'm just asking about another sentence I'm curious to know related to this question.

Comment: @WeatherVane 's original comment applies to your new sentence too. If it's *You!* (to get the person's attention) *Go to Sam's room...* that is an imperative, but if you is the subject (no pause) that is not an imperative and doesn't work as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the imperative mood implies that it is directed at "you". So if you is added, it may be a command, but it will not technically be in the  imperative. Tha does not make it wrong, nor not a command.